# the largest real part of the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hurwitz-matrices

I recently had an interesting observation but fail to come up with a rigorous explanation. What I observed is stated as follows. I am wondering if anyone is familiar with it.

Let $A$ be a real matrix, $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ be the largest real part of its eigenvalues. If we add (resp., substract) real positive numbers from its $i$-th diagonal entry, the new $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ will increase (resp., decrease).

For example, when $A=\left[ -100 -1000 ; 1000\quad 40\right]$, $\lambda_{\text{max}}=-30$, but when we change $A(2,2)$ to 10, $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ decreases to -40.

I have been thinking about it for many days, I really hope that someone could help me with it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to point you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem.
To me it seems exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have considered using this theorem, but to me this one can only help me to ascertain that the center of some discs will move according to the change of the diagonal entry. The eigenvalue, however, could lie in any point of the disc. As for determining the change of the exact value of the largest real part of the eigenvalues, the theorem seems inadequate.